# Update json nodes in Python using jsonpath

Tags: python, json, jsonpath

I'm trying to modify json data based on a jsonpath expression:

```
{
    "SchemeId": 10,
    "nominations": [
        {
            "nominationId": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Using something like

```
from jsonpath_ng import jsonpath, parse
jsonpath_expr = parse('$.SchemeId')
jsonpath_expr.find(data)
updated_json = jsonpath_expr.update(data, 'schemeId': 11)
```

I would like to update the `SchemeId` value, which should be possible using https://github.com/h2non/jsonpath-ng, however there are no examples. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I figured this out so I can share here. The update() method changes the values.

```
from jsonpath_ng import jsonpath, parse
import json
data = json.loads('''{"SchemeId": 10, "nominations": [ { "nominationId": 1 } ] }''')
jsonpath_expr = parse('$.SchemeId')
jsonpath_expr.find(data)
jsonpath_expr.update(data, 11)
print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```