# Changing dict content dynamically using Python

Tags: python, kubernetes, yaml

Say, I want to dynamically edit a Kubernetes deployment file that looks like this using Python:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend
spec:
  replicas: 4
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: guestbook
      tier: frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: guestbook
        tier: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: GET_HOSTS_FROM
          value: dns
        image: gcr.io/google-samples/gb-frontend:v4
        name: php-redis
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
```

I have a code that opens this yaml file where I want to change the content of spec.replicas branch from 2 to 4:

```
 with open(deployment_yaml_full_path, "r") as stream:
        try:
            deployment = yaml.safe_load(stream)
            if value_to_change[0] == 'spec.replicas':
                deployment['spec']['replicas'] = value_to_change[1]
        except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
            logger.error('There was a problem opening a deployment file in path: ',
                         deployment_yaml_full_path=deployment_yaml_full_path, exc=exc)
```

I would like to know if there's a way to avoid the hardcoded part here to something more dynamic:

```
if value_to_change[0] == 'spec.replicas':
                deployment['spec']['replicas'] = value_to_change[1]
```

Is there a way?

Comment: What is the hard-coded part? Do you want the code to be general to any value in `value_to_change`?

Comment: I'd like to the ['spec']['replicas'] or any other part in the yaml to be dynamic according to the value I pass in values_to_change[1]

Comment: This is the function call: 
    change_deployment_values(app_name='some_app_name', value_to_change=['spec.replicas', 4])

Answer (score 0):

```
target = value_to_change[0].split('.')

if len(target) == 2 and target[0] in deployment and target[1] in deployment[target[0]]:
    deployment[target[0]][target[1]] = value_to_change[1]
```

If the paths can be longer:

```
path_len = len(target)

d = deployment
path_exists = True
for i in range(path_len):
  if target[i] in d:
    d = d[target[i]]
  else:
    path_exists = False

if path_exists:
   d = value_to_change[1]
```

Comment: The path can be longer than 2 though.. This will not fit unfortunately

Comment: Made the solution general to longer paths

Comment: This could be the base for a recursion, but actually is like 'hard-coding' some cases. To crawl inside a dictonary means you actually change level each time you get a new key which value is a dictonary. you won't have problem changing the actual dictonary level to new one since the new object would be always the same.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to change the YAML to JSON/dictionary using `PyYaml`

```
import yaml
import json

with open('config.yml', 'r') as file:
    configuration = yaml.safe_load(file)

with open('config.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(configuration, json_file)
    
output = json.dumps(json.load(open('config.json')), indent=2)
print(output)
```

After that you would like to use:

```
class obj(object):
def __init__(self, d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(k, (list, tuple)):
            setattr(self, k, [obj(x) if isinstance(x, dict) else x for x in v])
        else:
            setattr(self, k, obj(v) if isinstance(v, dict) else v)
```

Usage Example:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 2}, 'd': ["hi", {'foo': "bar"}]}
>>> x = obj(d)
>>> x.b.c
2
>>> x.d[1].foo
'bar'
```

The last phase will be to change the value by string path:

```
from collections.abc import MutableMapping

def set_value_at_path(obj, path, value):
    *parts, last = path.split('.')

    for part in parts:
        if isinstance(obj, MutableMapping):
            obj = obj[part]
        else:
            obj = obj[int(part)]

    if isinstance(obj, MutableMapping):
        obj[last] = value
    else:
        obj[int(last)] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

> Disclaimer: this is solely for solace, fun and educational purpose

*I think the correct way to do what you want is to study json path, there is an easy example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59057672/update-json-nodes-in-python-using-jsonpath) and this stupid answer of mine could help you create the actual json path expressions!*

Well, this is the one-liner you should NOT use to achieve what you want in the most dynamic way possible:

```
exec(f'deployment{"".join([f"[##{val}##]" for val in value_to_change[0].split(".")])}={value_to_change[1]}'.replace('##','"'))
```

We create a list from the `value_to_change[0]` value splitting by dot.

```
  value_to_change[0].split(".")
```

We get each `val` in this list end we enclose it in "dictionary" syntax (hashtags.. well they can be anything you want, but f-strings do not support backslashes, hence I replace hashtags with the quotes after)

```
[f"[##{val}##]" for val in value_to_change[0].split(".")]
```

We `join` the vals in a `string` and `replace` the hashtags and add the `deployment` string

```
f'deployment{"".join([f"[##{val}##]" for val in value_to_change[0].split(".")])}={value_to_change[1]}'.replace('##','"')
```

The result will be this string... (what you would normally write to change that value):

```
'deployment["spec"]["replicas"]=50'
```

We perform actual **monstrosity** *exec*uting the string.
In my example `value_to_change[1]` is `50`

```
{
  "apiVersion": "apps/v1",
  "kind": "Deployment",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "frontend"
  },
  "spec": {
    "replicas": 50,
    "selector": {
      "matchLabels": {
        "app": "guestbook",
        "tier": "frontend"
      }
    },
    "template": {
      "metadata": {
        "labels": {
          "app": "guestbook",
          "tier": "frontend"
        }
      },
      "spec": {
        "containers": [
          {
            "env": [
              {
                "name": "GET_HOSTS_FROM",
                "value": "dns"
              }
            ],
            "image": "gcr.io/google-samples/gb-frontend:v4",
            "name": "php-redis",
            "ports": [
              {
                "containerPort": 80
              }
            ],
            "resources": {
              "requests": {
                "cpu": "100m",
                "memory": "100Mi"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Have FUN!

Answer (score 0):

The json path solution is like this

You just need `parse` function from `jsonpath_ng` library (pip install jsonpath_ng)

```
from jsonpath_ng import parse

# create the expression
expr = parse(f'$.{".".join(value_to_change[0].split("."))}')
# you can check if it works with expr.find(deployment) more after.

# actually change the value
expr.update(deployment, value_to_change[1])

# deployment['spec']['replicas'] now has changed
```

When you check with find you will see a lot of output, just focus on the first part:

```
expr.find(deployment)
>>> [DatumInContext(value=4, path=Fields('replicas')
```

As you can see the expression is really easy: `"$.path.to.value.you.want"`
If you wonder how to manage `list` inside, the syntax is the same as python `[]`, with inside the index, or `*` to say all the items in the list (and this is priceless!!)

[This](https://www.theclickreader.com/jsonpath-python/) is a very good place to learn everything you need!